# Node js: Mongo DB performance $in

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with 1121547 documents and I have to 5014 ids to search between these documents. Is it better to do a query with the $in operator, find its cursor and then go through the registries with eachAsync or Is it better do a for a loop in the Ids searching one by with find?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Better to use elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use $in for the search. 
- If you do find() for each id then you will be processing the documents at Mongo as well as in your code. But in $in they are processed at Mongo.
- Second point is all the operations like find() are scan methods they will look for the match in all documents unless you do indexing. so make sure the Ids that you are searching are indexed.